# Dojo migration for ie10 support

Tags: javascript, dojo

My current application uses dojo 1.2, I have to support IE 10 also, please suggest recommended dojo version and migration steps to it.

Comment: I believe you meant [tag:javascript], not [tag:java].

Comment: dojo 1.9 supports IE-10 refer the release notes [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.9)

Comment: May be you should try to migrate to dojo 1.10. But since you are using 1.2 then migration to 1.10 is not easy. http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Migrating-DOJO-FROM-1-2-to-1-9-td3998987.html

Comment: dojo 1.8.4 supports IE 10 http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.8 but i am worrying about migration steps

Comment: you can take a look at the below link. But it is for 1.7 and it supports IE 9. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/migration-17.html